# Unable to cast transparent proxy to type - Assembly Loading issue

Tags: c#, dll, prism

I am creating a plugin that is hosted in an application (called ETABS installed in my C drive). My plugin is a .dll file called Combinito.dll. I am also using Prism framework for my WPF application. ETABS requires that all plugins have a function called cPlugin as the "entry" point for the plugin. The plugin works fine when I have no **modules** in my plugin. As soon as I try to add a module to my blank plugin (that consists of just a blank window for testing) it does not work (it compiles but gives me an error during run-time at bootstrapper.Run()). The error is:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in Prism.Wpf.dll An
> exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
> Prism.Wpf.dll but was not handled in user code Unable to cast
> transparent proxy to type 'InnerModuleInfoLoader'.

After alot of research with my limited skills I was able to determine that this is issue is related to .dll loading (not sure?). I downloaded Fusion++ to have a log of the .dll being loaded once I launch ETABS and run my plugin. I tried to look at where Prism.wpf.dll is being loaded (shown in image below):
[dll loading log from Fusion++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uikr1.png)

First of all I noticed it was loaded twice. The second time however it fails to load. Here is what the logger says:

```
LOG: DisplayName = Prism.Wpf, Version=8.1.97.5141, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40ee6c3a2184dc59
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = ETABS.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 19\ETABS.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf/Prism.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf/Prism.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

Compared to the first time it was loaded:

```
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = ETABS.exe
Calling assembly : Combinito, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Program Files\Computers and Structures\ETABS 19\ETABS.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Prism.Wpf, Version=8.1.97.5141, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40ee6c3a2184dc59
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf/Prism.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files/Computers and Structures/ETABS 19/Prism.Wpf/Prism.Wpf.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/moustafa.el-sawy/source/repos/Combinito/Combinito/bin/Debug/Prism.Wpf.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\Users\moustafa.el-sawy\source\repos\Combinito\Combinito\bin\Debug\Prism.Wpf.dll
```

Notice how in the failed attempt it says  "calling assembly : unknown. Also it doesnt do the fifth attempt at finding it.

My code consists of one solution (visual studio) that is made up of 2 projects (the module and Combinito). Combinito serves as the main plugin (Shell).
***Plugin Code:***

*in my cPlugin.cs:*

```
Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();
bootstrapper.Run();
```

*Bootstrapper.cs*

```
 public class Bootstrapper : PrismBootstrapperBase
    {
        protected override IContainerExtension CreateContainerExtension()
        {
            return new UnityContainerExtension();
        }

        protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.Register<MainWindowViewModel>();
        }

        protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
        {
            base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();
        }

        protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
        {
            // Use local directory as module catalog
            return new DirectoryModuleCatalog { ModulePath = "Modules" };
        }

    }
```

I have one single Module (code below) that has a post-build command to copy the .dll in the bin/debug/Modules folder for my plugin and I have checked the folder myself after building (its there).

*Module class*:

```
using Combinito.Modules.LCGenerator.Views;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Regions;

namespace Combinito.Modules.LCGenerator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Register components of module with Unity/Prism
    /// </summary>
    [Module(ModuleName = "ModuleA")]
    public class LCGeneratorModule : IModule
    {
        
        public void Initialize()
        {

        }
        public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
        {
 
        }

        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Any hints are truly appreciated. Id really like to utilize Prism to create modules and make my plugin modular. Here is [Prism's Module documentation](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/modules.html) for the experts.

Comment: How does your plugin-directory look like? Which DLL is where? Do you have the Prism-DLLS in both your plugin-base-directory as well in the modules-directory?

Comment: @Haukinger my host software (ETABS) doesnt have any of my dll copied in the installation folder (C drive). My plugin-base directory (Combinito/bin/Debug) has Combinito.dll, Module dll, Prism.dll, Prism.Wpf.dll, Prism.Unity.Wpf.dll along with other prism dll's + Modules folder that contains the Module dll only.  My Module folder (Module/bin/Debug) contains Prism.dll, Prism.Wpf.dll, Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.dll and the module dll itself. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `Modules folder that contains the Module dll only` or `My Module folder (Module/bin/Debug) contains Prism.dll, Prism.Wpf.dll, Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.dll and the module dll itself` ? If the module needs DLLs, you should deploy them with the module, i.e. to the modules installation folder. To me, that's a strong argument _against_ modules in a separate folder.

Comment: I am still new to this; what do you mean deploy them with the module? I created the module using the Prism module template in visual studio and it automatically added Prism.Core and Prism.Wpf as references in the module project. Should my module/bin/debug only contain the module dll with no prism dlls?

Comment: Re-reading your comment; are you saying that in my modules folder inside my plugin-base I should also have the Prism.dll etc? I thought the module dll is attached to the plugin-base and would use Prism from there? Sorry im just thinking with my non-experienced brain - dont really have a solid understanding of how dll are loaded.